# Close all documents in one 'Tab Well' but not in others in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tabs

I have two 'tab wells' placed on two separate monitors. I have several documents (from same solution) opened in both the tab wells.

Now I want to close all the documents in first tab well, but not in the second well. Is there a command or keyboard shortcut for this?

I am currently using VS2013, but if such shortcut is available in VS2015, let me know.

Comment: By two separate monitors do you mean they are two separate systems altogether or is it two monitors connected to one CPU. I'm guessing it should be the latter, but wanted to confirm.

Comment: Connected to one CPU.